# Duplicate IDs in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to do some automatic code-generation for my JSF pages. Along with this a problem with duplicate IDs showed up, which I do not understand.

The follwing code snippet

```
<h:form id="myForm" prependId="true" >
    <p:panelGrid id="myPanel1">
         <p:panelGrid id="grid" />
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:panelGrid id="myPanel2">
        <p:panelGrid id="grid" />
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

results in an "Duplicat ID error", which says that the ID `myForm:grid` has already been found on my page. What I expected were two different IDs with the pattern `myForm:myPanel1:grid` and `myForm:myPanel2:grid`

In the component tree it shows those "panelIDs"

```
+id: myForm
   type: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm@3720dee3
        +id: myPanel1
         type: org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGrid@4f09255b
          +id: grid  <===============
           type: org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGrid@6173a1e6
        +id: myPanel2
         type: org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGrid@6e8a3505
          +id: grid  <===============
           type: org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGrid@339f13f5
```

What is the problem here? And how can I make those "grid-IDs" unique?

---

I am using 
PrimeFaces 4.0
Mojarra 2.1.27
Running on GF 3.1.2.2

(However, the problem also occures when using just plan JSF, so I do not tag this as a special PrimeFaces-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only [components](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) that implement [NamingContainer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) provide namespaces for descendant [component identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getId%28%29).

It is possible for a control to be a container without performing this function. [UIPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIPanel.html) instances generally only control layout and don't incur the overhead involved in this.